# How to find the value of the difference between two determinants divided by $(b-a)$ and $(b-c)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

The problem is as follows.

> Let $B$ to be:
>
> $B=\frac{\left|\begin{matrix}(a-b)&-2\\0&(b-c)\end{matrix}\right|-\left|\begin{matrix}3&3&3\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab\end{matrix}\right|}{(b-a)(b-c)}$
>
> After solving for $B$ which of the following expressions match the answer?.
>
> The choices given by my workbook are as follows:
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> 1.&c-a-1\\
> 2.&3b-a+1\\
> 3.&3c-a-1\\
> 4.&3c-3a-1\\
> \end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly how to understand the *official solution from my workbook* as it is difficult to get.

So the lines from below is the solution that is proposed by my book, could someone **help me please to understand what did the author meant?**

$B=\frac{\left|\begin{matrix}(a-b)&-2\\0&(b-c)\end{matrix}\right|-\left|\begin{matrix}3&3&3\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab\end{matrix}\right|}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

$B=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)-3\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab\end{matrix}\right|}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

$B=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)-\frac{3}{abc}\left|\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\\abc&abc&abc\end{matrix}\right|}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

$B=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)-\frac{3}{abc}\left|\begin{matrix}abc&abc&abc\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

$B=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)-3\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

Relying on Vandermonde's determinant:

$B=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)-3(b-a)(c-b)(c-a)}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

$B=\frac{(b-a)(b-c)[(-1)+3(c-a)]}{(b-a)(b-c)}$

$B=3c-3a-1$

Therefore the answer is choice 4.

That's where it ends the explanation of the official answer. But to me the most disturbing or confusing things from such conclusion is **how on earth does these factorizations are justified?**

I mean:

$\left|\begin{matrix}3&3&3\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab\end{matrix}\right|=3\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab\end{matrix}\right|$

$\left|\begin{matrix}3&3&3\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab\end{matrix}\right|=\frac{3}{abc}\left|\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\\abc&abc&abc\end{matrix}\right|$

$\frac{3}{abc}\left|\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\\abc&abc&abc\end{matrix}\right|=\frac{3}{abc}\left|\begin{matrix}abc&abc&abc\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|$

$\frac{3}{abc}\left|\begin{matrix}abc&abc&abc\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|=3\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|$

I'm confused exactly **why** do these manipulations work. Thus **I beg someone could explain to me these**

I do remember that when you factor out a term from a matrix or a determinant this must affect all rows:

For example:

$\left|\begin{matrix}2&4\\6&8\end{matrix}\right|=2\left|\begin{matrix}1&2\\3&4\end{matrix}\right|$

But in the earlier cases it **does seem to only affect the first row**, but is this valid?.

**Please I require someone could help me to address these doubts because I'm just totally confused**.

Thus it would really help me a lot if someone could help me to understand why you can also swap the rows and the determinant seem unaffected.

Comment: I think if we factor out a term from a matrix, it affects all rows, but in the case when we have to find the determinant, it is only for one row, not for all. So, if $A$ is a matrix with determinant $det(A)$, then $det(kA)=k^n det(A)$, where $A$ is an $n\times n $ matrix.

Comment: "I do remember that when you factor out a term from a matrix or a determinant this must affect all rows". This isn't quite right. If M is a matrix then $2M$ is indeed the matrix with all elements multiplied by 2. But $|2M|=2^n |M|$. That is, you get a factor of 2 for each row (or column) you multiply by a factor.

Comment: Substitute $a=b=0$ and $c=1$ to get one of the given solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant is a sum of products where no two multipliers in a product come from the same row or column. For example, for 3×3 matrix:

$$
\det\begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{vmatrix}=a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32} \\ - a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}-a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}-a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}
$$

See how in each of the term, we have all 3 indices (1,2,3) in the first place (row) and in the second place (column).

That means, that if we multiply the row by the same number $k$, exactly one element in each product will be affected:

$$
\det\begin{vmatrix}k a_{11}& ka_{12}&ka_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{vmatrix} = (ka_{11})a_{22}a_{33}+(ka_{12})a_{23}a_{31}+(ka_{13})a_{21}a_{32} \\- (ka_{13})a_{22}a_{31}-(ka_{12})a_{21}a_{33}-(ka_{11})a_{23}a_{32} = \\
k\left(a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32} - a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}-a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}-a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}\right) = \\
k \det\begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{vmatrix}
$$

The same is true for the columns.

Regarding the manipulations:

1. the first row was divided by 3
2. the first column was multiplied by $a$, the second by $b$, the third by $c$
3. we switched rows 2 and 3 and then 1 and 2. Each switch brought a $-1$ coefficient. Two of them resulted in the same value as before.
4. the first row was divided by $abc$

Comment: So you can freely multiply rows or columns by some $\lambda$ and divide out of the determinant and it will be **unaffected**. Can you include a proof for this or maybe a link on where I can see this?. You mentioned when you switch rows this brings a coefficient of $-1$ **why**?. Would the same happen if you switch columns?. Can you please attend these doubts which I have?.

Comment: You can look for those in any proper book on linear algebra. For example [Purdue pdf](https://www.math.purdue.edu/files/academic/courses/2010spring/MA26200/3_2.pdf), properties page 201, prooves page 206

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but I wonder, let's say, can you multiply one row and one column **simultaneously** and the determinant would not be affected?. Let's say: $\left|\begin{matrix}1&2\\3&4\end{matrix}\right|\xrightarrow[,2R\times 3]{1C\times 2}\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}\left|\begin{matrix}2&2\\18&12\end{matrix}\right|$ am I **getting you right?**.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in your belief that $\det(\lambda A)=\lambda\det(A)$ when $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Actually, when you multiply *one* row (or line) by $\lambda$, the determinant of the new matrix is the determinant of the original one time $\lambda$, and that's what is used in that solution.